# View.getX/Y and View.setX/Y below Android 3.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am working on a project that must work on Android 2.2 onwards, and I just realized I was using a 3.0+ method from View.

I have a menu that animates vertically sliding in/out when a button is pressed. When the animation finishes I update the View position with setY() method.

I tried to change it to getTop/setTop but it's not working properly, I suspect because getY is actually taking into account transformations and getTop is not (I guess animations are handled as transformations).

Any easy alternative for Froyo without modifying too much code?

This is the animation part:

```
    animationSlideInDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_down);
    animationSlideOutUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_up);
    animationSlideInDown.setDuration(200);
    animationSlideOutUp.setDuration(200);
    animationSlideInDown.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            if (menuInitialPosition == -1) {
                menuInitialPosition = menu.getY();
                menuHeight = menu.getHeight();
            } else {
                menu.setY(menuInitialPosition);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            menu.setY(menuInitialPosition);
        }
    });
    animationSlideOutUp.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            menu.setY(-menuHeight);
        }
    });
```

This is the slide_out transition:

```
<translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:fromYDelta="-100%"
android:toYDelta="0"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fillEnabled="true"

android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get position of particular view on the screen than you can use :

int[] locationOnScreen = new int[2];
menu.getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen);

And for setting view to particular position you can use LayoutParams and set left and top margin for the view.